# Vaadin 14 training "RouterAPI" is probably outdatedt, so mvn jetty:run raises an error. How do I need to change the POM file?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, pom.xml, maven-jetty-plugin, vaadin14

as stated I have trouble running mvn jetty:run with the existing vaadin exercise for routing in vs code. As the tutorial was already created under vaadin 10 the pom file is probably outdated, as the other trainigs worked perfectly fine with the mvn jetty:run command.
The exact error is:

```
No plugin found for prefix 'jetty' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\Dukatz\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]
```

Sadly I'm pretty new do web application development, so I don't have the slightest idea, how to make it work. Hopefully you can help me.
The Tutorial: [Vaadin Router Api Tutorial](https://vaadin.com/learn/training/v14-router)

the POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.vaadin.trainings.routing</groupId>
    <artifactId>exercises-routing</artifactId>
    <name>Routing Exercises</name>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>

        <!-- Dependencies -->
        <vaadin.version>13.0.5</vaadin.version>
        <servlet.api.version>3.1.0</servlet.api.version>

        <!-- Plugins -->
        <jetty.version>9.4.15.v20190215</jetty.version>
        <maven.war.plugin.version>3.1.0</maven.war.plugin.version>

    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
            <name>Vaadin Pre-releases</name>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Added to provide logging output as Flow uses -->
        <!-- the unbound SLF4J no-operation (NOP) logger implementation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet.api.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.war.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Implementation-Title>${project.name}</Implementation-Title>
                            <Implementation-Version>${project.version}</Implementation-Version>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jetty.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no Problem with the pom file. Because it's an older lesson, there was no pom file created for the whole project, but only in the specific paths (like \exercises or \solutions). So running `mvn jetty:run` couldn't work. There was no pom in the directory. I started it in VS-Code with the Maven-Explorer jetty plugin but

```
mvn jetty:run -f "c:\Users\Dukatz\Desktop\VadinTutorials\Vaadin14-RouterAPI\Exercises\pom.xml"
```

would do the job from the command line.
Thanks me! I won't delete the question because, one day there's maybe someone as dumb as me.

Comment: Could you accept your answer, then it helps other people who have run across a similar problem.